# java Variable cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, variables

The final line of code gives an error p1 cannot be resolved. I believe this is due to it not being in scope but i am unsure how to resolve this problem. Thanks any help appreciated.

```
switch (Player1) 
{
    case "Human":
    { 
        HumanPlayer p1 = new HumanPlayer(sc, theGame);
        break;
    }
    case "Simple":
    { 
        SimpleComputerPlayer p1 = new SimpleComputerPlayer();
        break;
    }
    case "Random":
    { 
        RandomComputerPlayer p1 = new RandomComputerPlayer();
        break;
    }
    case "Expert":
    { 
        ExpertPlayer p1 = new ExpertPlayer();
        break;
    }
}                                                            
p1.setMySymbol(SquareStatus.CROSS);
```

Comment: `p1` is unknown outside of your `case` blocks. Declare it before the `switch` .

Comment: aside from the variable being out of block scope, is this a good way of defining p1 as a mutable object. perhaps the player types are all descendants of some `Player` type, but maintaining this as those each have potentially different methods will become a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `Player p1` outside of the switch.

```
Player p1;
switch (Player1) {...}
if(p1 != null) p1.setMySymbol(SquareStatus.CROSS);
```

Comment: When this is done there is an error saying "Player cannot be resolved to a type". Any advice?

Comment: @Matt Yes, because it doesn't exist. I guessed your super class was named like that. Change it to the super class name you are using. It's the class what `ExpertPlayer`, `HumPlayer` etc. inheriting.

Comment: I think I'm getting there now haha but it is now complaining about duplicate variables.

Comment: @Matt I am not sitting at your desktop. Can't tell what is wrong. Besides that doesn't `duplicate variables` indicate something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

YOu have defined HumanPlayer inside case. define it outside switch

Answer (score 0):

When you use {} inside a function you are creating additional scope levels, any local variables defined in the scope are not visible outside of the scope.

Answer (score 0):

what about trying something in these lines

```
public static Object getPlayer()
    {
        String Player1 = "Human";


        switch (Player1) {
            case "Human": {
                return new HumanPlayer();

            }
            case "Simple": {
                return new SimpleComputerPlayer();

            }
            case "Random": {
                return  new RandomComputerPlayer();

            }
            case "Expert": {
                return  new ExpertPlayer();

            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

then maybe

```
worker.getPlayer().setMySymbol(SquareStatus.CROSS);
```

might have to do some

```
obj instance of HumanPlayer
```

somewhere.